# Is this race condition?

Tags: firebase, dart, nosql, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am make random 1:1 chat app with Flutter and Firestore.

I am question if I have race condition when I am connect second user to chat. This my client app code for add second user to Firestore (first user is already add to Firestore document):

```
await chatRoomReference.setData({
  ‘secondUserUID': uid,
});
```

When second user tap to chat I am remove option to enter this chatroom from all client UI.

But is possible that if third user tap to chat at same time (before UI get update from stream) he will also be add to database? Chat should not allow this.

Any thought?

Comment: It is. Do that from firebase functions instead, clients shouldn't.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for reply! Can have more explain?